# Debug using Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I work on RoR application. I would like to debug my app using Rubymine debugger. But I have to run my app on specific port on server. So my question Is. Should I change default port in Rubymine configuration on which webrick run? If so how? Or run app by rubymine? I don't know that are "correct" questions (correct I mean not stupid;)) But I'm fresh in Ruby technologies. Thanks for all answers.

Edit:
dax thank you for your answer I have changed port. Now serwer run  but I have in rubymine console information that:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.22, ruby-debug-base19x 0.11.30.pre15) listens on 127.0.0.1:43588
```

I should change fast debugger port to make it work. Am I right? But I don't have idea how to change it.

Edit:

After a while I get something like this:

```
30381: Exception in DebugThread loop: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Backtrace:
/home/arkency/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.6.2/lib/ruby-debug/interface.rb:175:in `read_command'
from: /home/arkency/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:84:in `process_commands'
from: /home/arkency/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:122:in `block in start_control'
[2014-04-13 15:18:08] ERROR SystemExit: exit
/home/arkency/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:126:in `exit'
```

Edit:
I removed debugger gem and now all works fine. Thanks for all replies;)

Comment: Do you have 'debugger' gem in your Gemfile? If yes, than remove it, RM doesn't work with it.

Comment: Yes, yes:) debugger gem was a problem thank you:) Now all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment: RubyMine doesn't work with `debugger` gem, so you have to remove it from Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can access/change your server port settings in the `edit configurations` menu.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4519470/2128691) for more details