# RubyMine debugger listening to wrong port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

I have a RoR application and I just started using RubyMine as my IDE. I set up a run configuration as follows:

[image: Run config]

However, when I to debug this configuration, I get the following error. Note that fast debugger is listening to the wrong port (50018 instead of 3000):

[image: Console output]

How can I change what port the debugger is listening to? It chooses a new random port to listen to every time I run it. This configuration worked fine a few times, and then suddenly stopped working. I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013834/debug-using-rubymine), but the debugger in the gemfile is already commented out.

Comment: I've noticed that when I change the port, it works fine. Even though fast debugger is listening on the 'wrong' port. For example, when I run the application on port 3005, it boots up fine, even though the debugger says its listening on 50708.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging works even though the debugger listens on a different port as the web server (intentionally). I just started up my debugger and set a breakpoint and it hit the breakpoint. This is a screenshot of my debugger (note port 65297 [image: Ruby Mine Debugger]

Try setting a breakpoint in your application controller to see if the debugger is functioning correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this isn't necessarily the issue (that the debugger is listening to the 'wrong' port). I can't start my application at all, because port 3000 is taken. The weird thing is RubyMine itself is occupying this port. If I close RubyMine and manually start my app via command line, it starts fine. If I open RubyMine, and try to start it via command line again, it fails and says the port is occupied. Any ideas?

Comment: Just saw your comment, but apparently you have another instance running in the background and didn't realize it. You need to [kill that process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473229/rails-server-says-port-already-used-how-to-kill-that-process)